# Sql Server sp_send_dbmail linked mysql server error

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

```
execute msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    etc etc
    @query = 'select * from Mysql...MemberRef4 as oi where oi.MemberId = 133363 '
```

The above is a query that I plugged into an existing working send mail method. MySql is a linked MySql database. I CAN run this query without any errors, correctly, by selecting the query code and F5. I am running this code and other MySql code joins with SqlServer and other linked servers - without any errors, including views/procs/etc.

However, the sp_send_dbmail method fails with :

```
Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.
```

Note: this is the first time I'm trying to put MySql queries in sp_send_dbmail

Any help please. I really don't want stored procs that create temp tables/etc :(

Comment: Is SP_send_dbmail working without query? Is mail getting trigger without @query? Check this first, I think the issues is with the security permissions.

Comment: I can send email from the same proc or code even - on an ongoing basis. There is no problem there. The new query code fails with above error message. But I can run that same query code in the same window without any changes (outside the send mail call). Put the query in send mail, it fails.

Comment: Have you tried the same pattern for a remote SQL Server instance? It might not work either. Anyway, as a workaround, I would simply try inserting the data into a local temporary storage first, then executing `sp_send_dbmail` with a query that gets the results from the local storage.